# Pre-post analysis with different number of pre and post measures at different time points

Tags: repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I'm trying to show the effect of an intervention. A group of about 30 individuals could hardly move their arms (because of traffic accidents). One surgery intervention was performed on each individual, after that intervention they gained some movility in the arm. But I need to show that such mobility had an impact using one assessment tool. The tool is called ARMTEST, individuals are assessed regarding their arm mobility using the ARMTEST, it ranges from 0 to 100.

Each individual was assessed using the ARMTEST several times: between 1 and 5 times before the surgery and between 1 and 7 timeas after the surgery.
Therefore some individuals have been assessed only once before and after the surgery but others have been assessed for example 5 times before and 7 times after the surgery.

The assessments were not performed at equal time intervals, for example one individual was assessed only one week before the surgery but other was assessed six months before the surgery. Similarly after the surgery they were not assessed at equal time intervals.

I just calculated the mean score of all assessments before surgery and after surgery and  the mean score is higher after surgery, but I'm trying to find a way to compare them formally, to show that there is a significant difference before and after surgery but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Do you have a control group?  Also, do you have other data on the injuries and on the patients?

Comment: What do you want to conclude? Having asked that, I don't think any analysis will give you a definite answer.